# SSH asks password when outside .ssh/ but not when inside .ssh/

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

This is the strangest I've ever encountered and I have no idea how to fix it.

I have many entries in my `.ssh/config` file because I use a number of keys.
When I `ssh` and I am located outside my `.ssh` folder I get prompted for a password (key was passwordless).

When I `cd` to my `.ssh` folder, same command `ssh {alias}` connects directly as expected (doesn't ask for password). Do you have ANY idea why this could be happening?

Comment: `strace` should give you a good hint what's going on.

Comment: And of course `ssh -vvv` might give you some good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the path to your key files for one of your rules isn't using an absolute path but a relative one. It's most likely a line like this on one of your `Host` connection definitions:

You have:

```
IdentityFile id_dsa
```

But the rule should be this:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Funny thing, non of my entries had path. Just the filaname of the key. Added absolute path to the failing one worked like a charm! Thanksy! xD